# where and how to serve files from , in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to node.js/express.js and I am reading some tutorials. I am confused because I am used to the simple apache logic, node.js/express.js logic confuses me. Please help me.

[This](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/) tutorial uses the default express routes to add/get data from a db. But, at the begging , at the part named "PART 2 – OK, FINE, LET'S DO "HELLO, WORLD!" edits the `...\ROUTES\INDEX.JS` file to add just a simple html page. Why is that?

1. Can I just use the `public` folder to serve my files and access the by using the same URL?
2. If I have like 50 files, I have to add 50 similar functions to my `...\ROUTES\INDEX.JS` so I can serve them ? Even the simplest static files ?
3. Can I just put all my files in the `public` folder and then edit `app.js` and `...\ROUTES\INDEX.JS` ?

Also I was reading the first chapter of the book ***Jump Start Node.js*** by Don Nguyen. It does not edit routes, just adds methods to the `app.js` and implements new modules (named `db` and `user`) for adding users to the db. This also adds a new `get` function to `app.js` for a simple `form.html` file.

1. Again, why can I use the `public` folder and then edit the `app.js` and create my own modules?
2. Again, If I have like 50 files, I have to add 50 similar functions to my `app.js` so I can serve them ? Even the simplest static files ?

   Finally,
3. What is the difference between the two methods ? In which case I use them ?
4. Which one is the best practice ?

Thank you very much

Comment: http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-static-content

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, serving files from `public` works. I asked if I can serve from `public` and still use app.js or routes, like the tutorials above do.

Answer (score 0):

To serve the folder named "public" as static files:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

The reason the tutorial did not put their 'simple' index page into `public`, is that their 'simple' page is *not static*. They pass in the data `{ title: 'Express' }` to the dynamic page.

If the title 'Express' is always going to be static, then yes you can serve it from `public`. However for the sake of the tutorial, we assume they might dynamically change the title from 'Express' to something else.

Comment: Thanks, I know, this line is by default in my `app.js` and serving files from `public` works. I asked if I can serve from `public` and still use `app.js` or routes, like the tutorials above do.

Comment: OK thanks. So what about my other questions? Do I have to add a method in `app.js` (or `index.js`) for every dynamic file? And what are the differences between the methods in the tutorials above? Thanks